# Check whether entity column is autoincrement

Tags: entity-framework, dbcontext, identity-column

I need to identify whether the dbcontext column is AutoIncrement column.
i.e: db.events, event_id column is AutoIncrement?

Answer (score 0):

DataAnnotations can be used for this ... for example:

```
<DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)> Property PersonId() As Integer
```

Given that, you could use reflection to check for what you need, or prevent it, etc.